# How to manage project in vagrant with the vendor to be outside of synced folder

Tags: php, symfony

For speeding up symfony in vagrant + virtualbox, I had been moved the directory vendor outside of the vagrant sync folder.

My project structure looks like below:

```
symfony-demo  
    |
    |---project
    |      |---app
    |      |---bin
    |      |---config
    |      |---src
    |      |---web
    |
    |---vendor
```

The root in nginx is /www/html/symfony-demo/project/web.
And the vagrant sync folder is  `"F:/project/symfony-demo/project",  "/www/html/symfony-demo/project"`

When using git to manage project. It will occur some troubles like that the local project is to be updated. But in the vagrant, the vendor isn't to be updated. I need manually update it in the vagrant.

It is hard to develop. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you keep vendor/ directory in sync

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It will be extremely slow when vendor directory in the synced folder. This directory need many IO operations I think.

Comment: Virtualbox is smart enough to just sync the folder when the 'change' event fired. Is your 'vendor' changed frequently?

Comment: No, it isn't `change` event. It maybe the `read` operation. This operation need too much time, about ~1s/page

Comment: Vendor is not the problem. Put your cache into memdir

Comment: I had already moved the `cache` directory and the `log` directory to /tmp. But it isn't affected. Only move the vendor outside the synced folder, the time of page load just need <100ms. I am sure it must be caused by the  vendor directory

Comment: If you're using Vagrant + NFS, it's normal to have a huge slowdown. I moved my dev env to Docker to solve this and have the best performances.

Comment: @Jean What your host OS is? My host OS is Win7. I think I am using Vagrant + VirtualBox shared folder. If I use Docker, it also needs VirtualBox to be installed which required by the Docker version of windows

Comment: Oh sorry, so Docker isn't native for your environment.. I use Linux