# Symfony2 app always has a 3 second wait between kernel.request and kernel.controller

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker, php-7

I'm trying to build this symfony2 application in a docker container with PHP7 and nginx with FastCGI PM.

Every time the application executes I get this mysterious 3 seconds of unaccountable execution time between the kernel.request and the kernel.controller.

You can see the odd request timeline in this screenshot:
[image]

This application doesn't have this behavior when I run it on my typical php5.5+apache2 config on my vagrant machine, so I'm not sure if it's something with my PHP config or PHP7, but I'm wondering if someone has seen something like this before and has any idea what might be happening here?

Edit here's the docker_compose config:

```
cafe:
  build: /opt/cafe
  ports: 
      - "9981:80"
  environment: 
      - "CAFE_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/cafe/cache"
      - "CAFE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/cafe"
      - "SF_ENV=local"
  volumes: 
      - /var/log/php7:/var/log/php7
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: like Zywj says in his answer this might be due to the way you are mounting files in Virtualbox, nfs or samba will always be a little slow. If your host is linux (not OSX) you should be able to run the container natively and thus have less performance hassles. Please confirm what your host machine is and if your files are mounted how, i.e you can share your vagrant details if this is what your are using

Comment: That was the first thing I guessed also, but I've set the docker configuration so that the files are not shared between the docker container and the host and the problem still persists. Also, I'm running another app in a different container except it uses HHVM instead of PHP and it doesn't have this problem even when the application files are shared with the host. The other peculiar thing about this is that it's almost always 3 seconds and some change, every time. It's like the page load is the extra MS after 3000 and something is just hanging for exactly 3 seconds and timing out.

Comment: @JesseGreathouse I think HHVM will buffer the content of vendor. And PHP will always to read the content of vendor.

Comment: @JesseGreathouse have you tried using Opcode in the current container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is curious, or having the same issue, I finally found the problem and it was not what I expected. When I was setting up this project for PHP7 I couldn't use the standard linux distro that I normally would have, I had to add all the configuration files myself.

After painstaking analyzing my code, I found out that the exact line, that was stalling, was a place I was running get_browser() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) in a kernel.controller listener. get_browser() was having a performance problem because of the browscap.ini file I used when setting up my php configuration in the container. I guess, for some reason, the browscap.ini file I used was having parsing issues or something. I changed it out with the lite_php_browscap.ini version and now it runs very very quick with no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also have been busy with Symfony performance within a box lately. The following quite recent article was the best recap I could find about it:

http://by-examples.net/2014/12/09/symfony2-on-vagrant.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `vendor` directory of Symfony. It needs too many IO operations. And the performance of VirtualBox synced folder is **very very slow** [the benchmark](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines).

You can move `vendor` directory outside the synced folder. Like my way below:
This is [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205888/how-to-manage-project-in-vagrant-with-the-vendor-to-be-outside-of-synced-folder).

But, at last, I have no best solution. So, I have moved to **pure linux** environment to write my code now.

Comment: It turned out to be something different, but I'm giving you the bounty anyways because you were the only person who posted an answer. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Very surprised. Thanks!